# Reference for Brownian motion as random fourier series

Tags: probability, reference-request, stochastic-processes, soft-question

I learned from these [notes](https://math.mit.edu/%7Ejerison/103/handouts/brownian.13.pdf) that in $0\leq t \leq \pi$, Brownian motion $W(t)$ can be written as,

$$
W(t)=\frac{a_0}{\sqrt{\pi}}t+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k\frac{\sin kt}{k}
$$

where $a_j\sim N(0,1),\forall j \in 0,1,2,\ldots$.

Can someone provide a textbook or peer-reviewed article reference for this result?

Comment: Isn't this the Karhunen Loève decomposition of the Brownian motion? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosambi%E2%80%93Karhunen%E2%80%93Lo%C3%A8ve_theorem

Comment: @TheBridge Thank you very much!